# Delimitate txt file in Excel 2003 using VBScript: errors

Tags: excel, vbscript

As with my previous questions, if I was using VBA this would be quite simple, but I have to use VBScript for this. I know how to import a txt file using OpenText like so:

```
objExcel.WorkBooks.OpenText "path\xxxx.txt"
```

This works fine, but the text isn't automatically put into columns in Excel. So I'm assuming I need to specify delimiters.

However, I get errors when trying to add options to the method. For instance

```
objExcel.WorkBooks.OpenText "path\xxxx.txt", , , xlDelimited, , , , , , True, " "
```

gives me an error saying "OpenText method of Workbooks class failed", code 800A03EC. What am I doing wrong? I've seen other people use the method like this. There's nothing special about how my txt file is formatted, it's just text.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VBScript doesn't recognise VBA named constants. If you want to use `xlDelimited` in your code, you must define the constant in your script:

```
Const xlDelimited = 1
```

otherwise you'll have to use the literal value as [chris neilsen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18464937/1630171) pointed out.

Another issue is that the 11<sup>th</sup> parameter in your method call is of the wrong type. That parameter must be a boolean value indicating if you want to use a different delimiter character. It's parameter #12 where you actually specify that custom delimiter character, so you need to change the line

```
objExcel.WorkBooks.OpenText "path\xxxx.txt", , , 1, , , , , , True, " "
```

into

```
objExcel.WorkBooks.OpenText "path\xxxx.txt", , , 1, , , , , , , True, " "
```

to make it work.

Of course, if you want to import space-delimited text, you could just set parameter #9 to `True` without specifying an `OtherChar` value:

```
objExcel.WorkBooks.OpenText "path\xxxx.txt", , , 1, , , , , , True
```

See the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837097.aspx) for further details.

Answer (score 2):

VBScript does not have named constants.

Use

```
objExcel.WorkBooks.OpenText "path\xxxx.txt", , , 1, , , , , , True, " "
```

Comment: Sorry, but that didn't work. Maybe I'm missing something else?